# VS2010: how to remove/hide the "External Dependencies" folder in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 they added to all projects a virtual directory called "External Dependencies":

[alt text http://koper.wowpanda.net/externaldeps.PNG](http://koper.wowpanda.net/externaldeps.PNG)

It really bothers me especially because if there is a normal folder named "Apple" and one named "Deep" it will be in between the two, and also the information it gives is, in my opinion, completely useless.

---

**Is there any way to remove or hide it?**

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Don't know if you figured this out yourself but looking at [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/raulperez/archive/2010/03/19/c-intellisense-options.aspx) you can disable it in the Options dialog (from the Tools menu).

On the right side panel expand the Text Editor section, then expand C/C++ and then click on Advanced. Set the Disable External Dependencies Folder to True and restart Visual Studio.

As mentioned by Michael in the comments, apparently you don't need to restart Visual Studio but can just close and re-open the solution to see the effects.

Comment: Thanks for this question & answer. I found the "External dependencies" folder to be useful coz once when I did an "exclude from project" for stdafx.h, I found it in 'external dependencies' and was able to include it back into the project. Am still a newbie to VC++ programming.

Comment: You will have to close and reopen the solution for this setting to take effect.

Comment: The same option also exists in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Now why would this be under Text Editor?

Comment: We have a large solution and quite often when opening a file (using File/Open or via right-clicking on a #include, etc.) it will open the file from the External Dependencies folder of some random project, expanding it as it does.  Our External Dependencies folders have hundreds (possibly thousands!) of files in them.  It's very annoying.  Glad I can turn this off.

Comment: If you're on VS 2015 and developing C++/CLI WinForms, be careful with this option as it renders the visual form designer unusable (_"The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed."_)

Comment: I like "Track Active Item In Solution Explorer" option and this External Dependencies folder spoiled all the fun. Thanks for the tip how to get rid of it!

Comment: In VS2022, go to tools -> options and type 'sources' to search box