# Why I got an External Dependencies folder (shortcut) in the solution explorer window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, glsl

I have Qt5 and vs2010 in my computer
     qmake -tp vc chapter01.pro   then open it in vs2010:

[image: folder shortcut]      [image: unfold the External Dependencies shortcut]

Why I got an External Dependencies folder (shortcut) in the solution explorer window?

It seems the current program is using the header files inside the  External Dependencies folder (shortcut) .  How to disable this folder or how to stop the program using header files in this folder?

Comment: this looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466286/vs2010-how-to-remove-hide-the-external-dependencies-folder-in-solution-explor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS2010: how to remove/hide the "External Dependencies" folder in Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466286/vs2010-how-to-remove-hide-the-external-dependencies-folder-in-solution-explor)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are external dependencies, of course - which Visual Studio (IntelliSense) found that your project is using.

If this bothers you too much, you can hide this folder by going into **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Text Editor** -> **C/C++** -> **Advanced**.
Find **Disable External Dependencies Folders**, set it to **True** and restart Visual Studio!

Comment: Thanks, the External Dependencies Folder disappears. However, the program is still using the header files in that folder and causes many errors: 1>D:\APP\Qt5\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\GLES2/gl2.h(38): error C2371: 'GLintptr' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          D:\OpenGL\glew-1.5.4\include\GL/glew.h(1615) : see declaration of 'GLintptr'
1>D:\APP\Qt5\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\GLES2/gl2.h(39): error C2371: 'GLsizeiptr' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          D:\OpenGL\glew-1.5.4\include\GL/glew.h(1614) : see declaration of 'GLsizeiptr'

Comment: I saw your another post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723048/. Unfortunately, this "External Dependencies" doesn't have any connection with multiple defined symbols - it is just list of files which are included in some points of your program.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, that's my post. the gl2.h belongs to the External Dependencies Folders and a variable in it caused redefinition?

Comment: @lightrek - gl2.h belongs to the external dependencies folder because your code is using it at some point (perhaps even in the qt library itself). Unfortunately, you can't edit files in that folder - this is only for showing all included files, and you need to delete line where it is included and it will be removed from this window. However, doing this in library code most certainly leads to breaking the library. P.S. I'm glad that I've helped in the other question.